# How to save base64 directly to mongoose in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save an image not in my server but in my database.

this is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var categorySchema = new Schema({
    img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

now in my router I'm getting this base64 image with a long string.

```
{ '$ngfDataUrl': 'data:image/png;base64,long-String'}
```

I want to know how do I save this information in my mongoose db database so far i have this.

```
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {

var category = new Category();
category.img.data = req.body.category.img;

category.img.contentType = 'image/png';

category.save(function (err) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    res.sendStatus(200)
});
```

but obviously that is not working i get this error.

> Error: ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Buffer failed for value "{
>   '$ngfDataUrl': 'data:image/png;base64, long-String'}

Thanks in advance I'm in saving files.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to actually pull out the base64 string from the request body, and save that.

Is `req.body.category.img` equal to `{ '$ngfDataUrl': 'data:image/png;base64,long-String' }`, where `long-String` is the base64 representation of the image?

If so, do something like this:

```
const category = new Category();

const img = req.body.category.img;

const data = img['$ngfDataUrl'];
const split = data.split(','); // or whatever is appropriate here. this will work for the example given
const base64string = split[1];
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64string, 'base64');

category.img.data = buffer;

// carry on as you have it
```

Comment: I got the same error. Changing the line to `new Buffer(base64string, "base64")` worked